# 500 Internal Server Error when updating htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using a quiz plugin for WP which caused a 504 Gateway Timeout after adding too many questions.

The developer told me to update my `.htaccess` file with the following code:

```
php_value max_input_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 5000
```

This is the `.htaccess` code before I added the 3 lines of code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And this is after I've added the code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
php_value max_input_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 5000
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also tried doing it like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

php_value max_input_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 5000

# END WordPress
```

However, both cause a 500 Internal Server Error.
I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong and was hoping to get your insight on it.

Here's a link to the FAQ / Article the developer of the plugin told me to use.
https://www.ohmyquiz.io/knowledgebase/get-fatal-error-save-big-quiz/

Comment: If you're running PHP in CGI mode then `php_value` and `php_flag` directives in .htaccess won't work. If this is the case you'll need to create a php.ini file at the document root and add the values that way.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this? Before # BEGIN Wordpress, This must work.

```
php_value max_input_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 5000

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Well, yes it will solve the 500 error, but then I'm back where I started trying to solve the 504 error.

Comment: Mr Riksson You can check it now.